# Count the values count which got from the url parameters React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the values from url parameters like this.

```
http://localhost:3000/#/bookingSummary?movieid=3232&movieName=Mortal%20Kombat&seats=A6,5,5,A6,A6,5
```

then I get the values and put them into an array as follows

```
var movieData = []
    componentDidMount() {
        let movieInfo = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
        console.log(movieInfo.movieid) 
        this.setState(movieInfo)
        console.log(movieInfo.seats)          
        movieData = movieInfo 
}
```

then I want to count how many seats are in seats parameter
I have no experience in React an explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: You want to count how many elements in `movieInfo.seats`?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes i want to know how many seats are there

Comment: `movieInfo.seats` is an array or a JSON object? If you are not 100% sure post it on question please =)

Comment: it's coming in my URL parameter. not from API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `console.log(movieInfo.seats)` shows `"A6,5,5,A6,A6,5"` (so, `movieInfo.seats` is a string), to count how many seats are in seats parameter you could use `.split()` function.

This function accepts a separator as input and returns an array of strings. So:

```
let arrayOfStrings = movieInfo.seats.split(',')
```

Now `arrayOfStrings` looks like:

```
["A6","5","5","A6","A6","5"]
```

So to count how many seats are in seats parameter you have just to call:

```
arrayOfStrings.length
```

Comment: console.log(movieInfo.seats) shows as "A6,5,5,A6,A6,5" not as  ["A6,5,5,A6,A6,5"]

Answer (score 1):

Well i may be mistake but if you have your query as a string, you just can do:

```
const seatsNumber = queryString.split("seats=")[1].split(",").length;
```

This will return you length of seats params. They are duplicated there though so to have length of uniq seats you can do next:

```
const seats = queryString.split("seats=")[1].split(",");
const uniqSeatsNumber = [ ... new Set(seats)].length;
```

But this is nothing with React, just plain JS. Hope I understood you right!